# Trasmitting data from pressure transducer to phone/web server

Tags: electrical-engineering, pressure

I am creating a 24 hour blood pressure monitor that is designed to be sleek and comfortable, I have decided on The Honey Well Series NBP AN transducer (see more info here: [Basic Board Mount Pressure Sensors](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/187/honeywell-sensing-basic-board-mount-pressure-senso-740338.pdf), p13) I want to connect that to a board so that the data can be transmitted wirelessly, or by cable to a phone or computer, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your sensor has an analog output. If your comfortable with prototype level work, get an Arduino that has analog inputs then connect a bluetooth module such as the HC-05. Then, you can transmit that data using some code that I wrote to send multiple sensors in columns. You can modify this code to your needs.

[sending sensor data - serial over bluetooth](http://www.jmaturner.com/sensors.html)

Your next task would be to write software, but you can view this data on a PC or phone using a terminal program like Teraterm.

Answer (score 3):

One such way transfer data is to use a Internet of Things (IOT) platform. You will need at minimum a microcontroller and wifi module. Currently some semiconductor vendors produce a both the microcontroller in a system on a chip (SOC) form factor. Either way you can access pressure sensor data via the microcontoller use the wifi connection to transmit the data to the web. Take a look at following two option from Texas Instruments.

- [Internet-of-Things Solution for MCU Applications CC3100](http://www.ti.com/product/CC3100) + [TIVA TM4C123](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/launchpad/launchpads-connected-ek-tm4c123gxl.html)
- [SimpleLink Wi-Fi CC3200 LaunchPad (Both microcontroller and Wifi in one package)](http://www.ti.com/tool/cc3200-launchxl)

There are also other vendor that offer similar solutions. I will listed few below under references.

There are other options, microcontroller + cellular, Microcontroller + BLE, BLE to smartphone + internet.

I suggest that you do a little research to narrow down the options. At which point you can post a question specific to your option so detail solution can be provided.

---

**References:**

- [CONNECT TIVA CONNECTED LAUNCHPAD TO EXOSITE CLOUD USING TI SIMPLELINK WIFI CC3100](https://markelthinkslearnscreates.wordpress.com/tag/wifi/)
- [Data Storage and Retrieval with ThingSpeak for Electric Imp Connectivity](http://community.thingspeak.com/tutorials/electric-imp/data-storage-and-retrieval-with-thingspeak/)
- [Adafruit.io Internet of Things Feather ESP8266 - WiFi Starter Kit](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2680)
- [EMW3165 - Cortex-M4 based WiFi SoC Module](http://www.seeedstudio.com/EMW3165-CortexM4-based-WiFi-SoC-Module-p-2488.html)
- [SparkFun IoT Wifi Starter Kit](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13865)
- [IoT Starter Kit from AT&T](https://starterkit.att.com/)